# How do I understand this remove method in heap data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

Given the following code:

```
public Node remove() {
    Node rootNode = heapArray[0]; // set the root node 
    heapArray[0] = heapArray[--currentSize]; // putting the value of the last index in the array at 
    // the 0th index 

    trickleDown(0); // call the trickle down method starting at the 0th index 

    return rootNode; // we return the root node because that will be replaced by another node 
}

private void trickleDown(int idx) { // idx is the index 

    int largerChildIdx; // larger child index 
    Node top = heapArray[idx]; // save last node into top variable ????

    // will run as long as idx is not on the bottom row (has at least 1 child)
    while(idx < currentSize/2) {
        int leftChildIdx = 2*idx +1;
        int rightChildIdx = 2*idx +2;

        // figure out which child is larger
        if(rightChildIdx < currentSize /* check to make sure we are not all the way at the end of the heap
           */ && heapArray[leftChildIdx].getKey() < heapArray[rightChildIdx].getKey()) {
            largerChildIdx = rightChildIdx;
        } else {
            largerChildIdx = leftChildIdx;
        }
        if(top.getKey() >= heapArray[largerChildIdx].getKey()) {
            // successfully made root the largest
            break;
        }
        heapArray[idx] = heapArray[largerChildIdx];
        idx = largerChildIdx; 
    }

    heapArray[idx] = top;

}
```

---

I have a question for this line:

*while(idx < currentSize/2)*

Why is it idx < currentSize/2? What does this accomplish when we are trying to remove from the heap?

Comment: Hi! You should probably add some additional tags to identify the programming language directly, which will allow better searching for this question and allow others to help given the selected language.

Answer (score 0):

In a heap, half of the nodes are leaf nodes: have no children. So if `idx` is greater than or equal to half the number of nodes, you know that the node at that position has no children. Consider:

```
           1
        2     3
       4 5   6
```

The heap has six nodes. Three of them are leaf nodes.

If a node doesn't have children, then it's already at the bottom level: there's no reason to continue trickling down.